# How can I POST some values to another page with Wt?

Tags: c++, post, wt

I have a WAnchor to another page, which changes the internal path. I also have a function `internalPathChange()` that reacts to `internalPathChanged()` and that calls the right function depending on the internal path.

How can I use POST to give values from the first page to the second page?

Comment: Hey Neyuh, nice question. To make it better, post a skeleton overview of your Wt code keeping the relevant bits, so that Pieter can update the answer to show how the sample would apply to your post! Best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

You should work with widgets. Wt doesn't known the concept of post and different html pages.

A great example can be found [here](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/src/hangman) in the file HangmanGame.C. 
You create your own widgets, and in the constructor of those widgets you specify which values you need. Then they use a `Wt::WStackedWidget` for displaying only the new "page".

They use following code:

```
void HangmanGame::handleInternalPath(const std::string &internalPath)
{
  if (session_.login().loggedIn()) {
    if (internalPath == "/play")
      showGame();
    else if (internalPath == "/highscores")
      showHighScores();
    else
      WApplication::instance()->setInternalPath("/play",  true);
  }
}

void HangmanGame::showHighScores()
{
  if (!scores_)
    scores_ = new HighScoresWidget(&session_, mainStack_);

  mainStack_->setCurrentWidget(scores_);
  scores_->update();

  backToGameAnchor_->removeStyleClass("selected-link");
  scoresAnchor_->addStyleClass("selected-link");
}

void HangmanGame::showGame()
{
  if (!game_) {
    game_ = new HangmanWidget(session_.userName(), mainStack_);
    game_->scoreUpdated().connect(&session_, &Session::addToScore);
  }

  mainStack_->setCurrentWidget(game_);

  backToGameAnchor_->addStyleClass("selected-link");
  scoresAnchor_->removeStyleClass("selected-link");
}
```

So in this example the `HighScoresWidget` and `HangmanWidget` are the "pages" to which you want to post values.